# Which distributed cache?

Tags: asp.net, caching

I needed to find a way that two applications can use the same cache, and after some quick research it seems that we will need a distributed cache to achieve this.  Further Googling turns up a number of solutions, [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/ncache_express.html), [SharedCache](http://www.codeplex.com/SharedCache), [Velocity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc655792.aspx), [memcached](http://www.codeplex.com/memcachedproviders).  This cache will be used for caching webpages in a Microsoft Enviroment using Asp.Net 3.5.

So my question is what experiences do you have with these, or other, technologies.

Answer (score 1):

We have been using Memcached for some time now and it works like a charm. It is really stable and the overall performance is also pretty good.

You can make use of the "Memcached Providers" project at codeplex.com to easily integrate it with .net.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the solution you require a low-tech option might be to persist the results/data to a network share.

Then have each machine hold a cached version (perhaps use the ASP.NET cache or Enterprise Library) of the data with a corresponding cache dependency.

To answer your question I have heard excellent things about NCache and Memcached.

Comment: I would argue that is anything but low-tech compared to an off the shelf distributed cache solution

Comment: It really depends on the desired solution, budget and the deployment scenario. However I would strongly recommend purchasing an enterprise product (like those listed above) in most cases.