# Is there a way to have a HttpCache shared between process?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, .net-4.0

Is there a way to have a HttpCache shared between process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is an out-of-process cache. Most (all?) of them are distributed. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856959/which-distributed-cache) for a list of available distributed caches usable in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Windows Server AppFabric

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx

Comment: AppFabric is deprecated technology; Microsoft recommends Redis caching as a replacement.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabric/archive/2015/06/19/appfabric-1-1-for-windows-server-support-lifecycle-extension-4-11-2017.aspx

Comment: No, but it is now, and users seeing this answer should be aware of that fact before they consider going with this technology.  My comment wasn't meant as a denigration of your answer (I would have downvoted otherwise), simply informing readers of the current state of affairs with AppFabric.